# Why have all my lab routers set their OSPF priority to 0?

Tags: cisco, ospf

I have 4 routers in my lab. FR1 is the frame relay switch (2621), R1(2621), R2(2651) & R3(2651) are all connected in a mesh using sub interfaces - R1 has pvc to R2&R3 and so on. Without OSPF I can ping all points successfully. With OSPF I can also ping all the loopbacks built onto the routers. OSPF seems to work but when I do:

```
#show ip ospf neighbor
```

the neighbours show as FULL but with 0 priority - and checking the detail each router has 0.0.0.0 as their DR.

I'm about to try changing the priorities, but given the fact I did a write erase before building the lab this evening, what could cause the priorities to move from the default of 1 to 0?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On frame-relay point-to-point interfaces, your OSPF priority is set to zero automatically. Also you have no DR election on a p2p links

Comment: Thanks! I'll fire up a switch and watch the elections using a broadcast network - apparently I'll see more interesting results.

Comment: Yeah, OSPF network types is a 'fun' subject. p2mp is essentially a bunch of p2p links so you see the same behaviour. Broadcast and non-broadcast elects DRs so priorities come into play

Comment: I'll confirm now that connecting the routers using a 2950 switch instead of the frame cloud has given me the results I expected. Thanks @mellowd!